# How to update cost for a specific shipping zone?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How to update the shipping cost for a specific zone name and method id?

```
foreach (WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones() as $shipping_zone) {
    if($shipping_zone['zone_name'] == 'Hrvatska') {
        foreach($shipping_zone['shipping_methods'] as $shipping_method) {
            if($shipping_method->id == 'flat_rate') {

                $new_cost = 5;
                // how to update cost?

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it with

```
$new_cost = 5;
$shipping_method->instance_settings['cost'] = $new_cost ;
update_option( $shipping_method->get_instance_option_key(), apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shipping_' . $shipping_method->id . '_instance_settings_values', $shipping_method->instance_settings, $shipping_method ) );
```